# How to make Assert.AreEqual pass on POCOs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Assert.AreEqual is failing on POCOs. It, however, is  not failing on individual items in POCOs. How to make it work on full POCOs in VS 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your POCOs override `Equals` in an appropriate way? If not, that's the problem. Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and you should be fine.

That's assuming there's only one notion of equality which you need to cover. An alternative is to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` in another class, and use that. (I don't know offhand whether `Assert.AreEqual` takes an optional `IEqualityComparer<T>` parameter, but you could always call it explicitly.)

Answer (score 2):

you could look into the [expected objects library](http://www.aspiringcraftsman.com/2011/06/28/introducing-the-expected-objects-library/).  its very neat and handles all of your comparison logic for you behind the scenes, making your code significantly easier and slimmer.  you can even tell it to ignore types, so if you want to just check a couple properties of an object, you can compare it with an object, or anything for that matter.

Comment: Whilst this may be an option, it is one I would be wary of, as it might lead you to believe that your objects are equal, when they would not be considered so when using many of the methods and classes in the framework.  ie an object would not be considered to be part of a collection still, as this would use `Equals` to perfom that check.And I don't think this would address the OPs use of `Assert.AreEqual` would it?  He would have to use the asserts on the ExpectedObject.  Unless I am misunderstanding something...

Comment: @sam, not sure what you mean.  this expected objects library is not for use in production code, but in unit testing only, so their real world equality is not the point, its use is to check that the object you've received from your test is what you expect it to be.  whether you expect all fields to be equal, or only care if some fields is up to you.  i just don't see the sense in mucking up something simple like a poco with code that has the sole purpose of checking the equality of an object in a test.

Comment: if the OP is using `Assert.Equal` to check if two objects he created are indeed equal this is very different from verifying that the object is what you expected it to be. Expected objects might help simplify your tests, but it will not help at all if the **point** of the test is to create 2 objects with the same values and then verify that they are considered Equal to each other. If you are creating a second object just to check values of the first then I can see the value, but it is not clear from the OPs question that this is the case. I just wanted to make this distinction clear.

Answer (score 2):

The tests are failing because **your objects are not equal**.  They may have the same values in their fields, but this does not make them equal.  By default objects are equal if they have the same address and so they are the same object.

To get the behaviour that you want (which is that you want objects which have properties with the same values to be equal) you need to override `Equals` and define what it is that makes your objects equal.  If this is all properties then check all properties here.  If it is just some then only check those.  Do whatever needs to be done to determine equality in your context.

If you are overriding `Equals` you should also override `GetHashCode` and ensure that when  `Equals` is true for two objects `GetHashCode` return the same value for both.